# Reducing after filtering doesn't add up with jq

Tags: json, select, jq, lookup

I have the following data:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "example-1",
    "amount": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "amount": 42
  },
  {
    "name": "example-2",
    "amount": 6
  }
]
```

I would like to filter objects with a `.name` containing "example" and reduce the `.amount` property.

This is what I tried to do:

```sh
json='[{"name":"example-1","amount":4}, {"name": "foo","amount":42}, {"name": "example-2","amount":6}]'

echo $json | jq '.[] | select(.name | contains("example")) | .amount | add'
```

I get this error:

> jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over number (4)

I think that the output of `.[] | select(.name | contains("example")) | .amount` is a stream, and not an array, so I cannot add the values together.

But how could I do to output an array instead, after the `select` and the lookup?

I know there is a `map` function and `map(.amount) | add` works, but the filtering isn't here.

I can't do a `select` without `.[] |` before, and I think that's where the "stream" problem comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `add/0` expects an array as input.

Since it's a useful idiom, consider using `map(select(_))`:

```
echo "$json" | jq 'map(select(.name | contains("example")) | .amount) | add'
```

However, sometimes it's better to use a stream-oriented approach:

```
def add(s): reduce s as $x (null; . + $x); 

add(.[] | select(.name | contains("example")) | .amount)
```

Comment: Oh nice! I found something like that and I had tried but couldn't get it to work. Thank you!